# Set Access 2010 record locking to optimistic locking through OleDb (C#)

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, oledb

I am communicating with **Access 2010** through **OleDb** in **C#**.
How can I set the **locking type** to use **optimistic locking** from C#?

In case anyone wonders, I am using this connection string to connect to my Access database:

```
// Set the data source string.
_sqlCon = new OleDbConnection(
    String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=True", databasePath)
);
```

**Update #0**

I found some information about `adLockOptimistic` from **ADO** on the Microsoft MSDN website (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee252458(v=bts.10).aspx) which might be totally irrelevant because I am using **OLE**.

**Update #1**

I tried to add the following to the connection string:

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=True;LockType=3;"
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=True;Lock Type=3;"
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=True;LockType=adLockOptimistic;"
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=True;Lock Type=adLockOptimistic;"
```

Which all result in the following exception:

> Could not find installable ISAM.

I'd expected it not to work, but hey, who knows if you don't try.

**Update #2**

If it is possible to define this property in my Access database, that solution is perfectly fine too! However, this should be a database setting and not a client specific setting and **if** it is possible from C#, that method has my preferences.

**Contextual information:**

> I am doing a concurrency stress-test on my Access database (over a network). I have about 20+
>   clients (little C# programs) that are reading **the same record** from
>   **the same table** as fast as possible for each client. This gives a lot of `database is in 'Admin' mode by ..`
>   exceptions and I catch these exceptions in my little C# client. I want to
>   be able to read these records at the same time to tackle a bigger
>   problem in one of my applications. I can easily solve this problem by switching to a "*real*" database system but this is unfortunately not possible.
>
> If the problem above is solved in any other way, I am still really interested in how to tell Access to use different locking types (from OleDb/C#).

Comment: Have you tried using an `OleDbTransaction` with `System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted`?

Comment: No, I have no idea what that is but I will check it out tomorrow at work. Thank you for giving me a pointer!

Comment: Just throwing it out there: another possibility (or not, depending on your configuration) is to use the Jet driver to connect (the "native" driver of Access). This also allows you to enable row-level locking (which is not synonymous with optimistic locking, but it is a factor) by using the `Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1` connection string setting.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have tried your suggestion but I am still getting the same exceptions. As far as I am aware, Access is by default already locking by row-level. Still thanks for your suggestion1

Comment: @GordThompson After some googling and testing I am able to implement that in the SQL statements like UPDATE & INSERT. But for retrieving data from the database I'm having some trouble with it. Also I have come to an idea to fix the problem in my contextual information, which I am going to test right now. That still leaves one question open: How can I change the locking type Access 2010 uses from C#/OleDb?

Comment: Locking and transaction isolation levels are interrelated. For example, the description for IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted says that "no shared locks are issued and no exclusive locks are honored" (ref: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). I have not seen any options in System.Data.OleDb that seem to match the adLockOptimistic option for (COM) ADO Recordset objects.

Comment: Aha! So based on the transaction isolation level that I set, the different lock types are utilized. Could you submit that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Technically, optimistic locking is equivalent to the snapshot isolation level, but I very much doubt the ACE driver maps it this way, as snapshot was specifically added for SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gord Thompson wrote:

> Have you tried using an OleDbTransaction with System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted?
>
> Locking and transaction isolation levels are interrelated. For
> example, the description for IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted says that
> "no shared locks are issued and no exclusive locks are honored" (ref:
> here). I have not seen any options in System.Data.OleDb that seem to
> match the adLockOptimistic option for (COM) ADO Recordset objects.